# History back to a page with facebook like button produces a white area on the bottom in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, facebook-like, browser-history

If I use the history back button of my browser to navigate back to a page with a facebook like button somewhere at the bottom, chrome shows some additional white space at the bottom of the page after the `<html>`-Tag.

- The white area is not there when I navigate on the same page normally (not using browser history)
- Using the element inspector I see that the `<html>`-Tag closes just where the white area starts.
- It occurs even with `overflow: hidden;` on the `<html>`-Tag
- If I remove the fb like button from the page, there is no such white gap.
- It seems to be browser specific as I can't reproduce it in Firefox.

Does anybody know where that comes from and how to get rid of it?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701869/facebook-like-button-renders-1000px1000px-after-pressing-back-on-browser-on-chr

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue. I have a Like button on my product pages and if you click the back button and end up on a page where a like button is the button loads late and is hidden behind other elements.

I found a piece of code that helped but didn't completely solve the issue. I can't remember the code but if you search enough you can find it and maybe solve your issue.